# How to debug Azure web role running in the cloud?

Tags: .net, azure, remote-debugging, visual-studio-debugging, azure-web-roles

We need to debug an issue that manifests itself ONLY in the cloud. It doesn't show up in the emulators (even with cloud connection strings etc). We have RDP installed on the staging web-role instance and have WebDeploy enabled on it too for quick-and-easy debugging/code changes.

What we'd like is something more powerful, where our local VS2010 (Ultimate) can set/trigger breakpoints on the remote web role and inspect local variables etc.

Does anyone know of a way of setting the above up?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ok, so I spent a few hours struggling with this due to combination of Azure SDK updates, incorrect tutorials, VS2012 quirks. What GertH said above is true in theory (thank!) but without working details at a systemic level it doesn't work so it's not very useful practically.

I've documented my working experience for future warriors at http://antirandom.com/2012/09/remotely-debugging-a-windows-azure-webrole-via-visual-studio-debugger/

Comment: Ideally you'd put a few main points of the solution from the link here... link only answer bad. But that is a lengthy post, so not sure how you'd do it ^^.

Answer (score 2):

In VS 2012 there's an easier way of doing Web Role debugging, as the remote debugger can be exposed as a TCP service endpoint. So you won't need the Azure Connect part anymore.

A great blog post is here: http://blog.fullscale180.com/remote-debugging-windows-azure-cloud-services-with-visual-studio-2012/

As a bonus, the remote tools are automatically configured and started when the WebRole itself is started, so you won't care when the role gets recycled.

Comment: In all cases the remote debugger is a TCP service - you want to use Azure Connect to isolate debug traffic over the VPN interface (versus over your production network interface). Not because it's the 'only' way of doing it. The part of automatically installing inside the role (off blob) is cool, but required app code changes. In fact it's possible to pick and choose different steps from the above link and mix it with the marked answer. The marked answer documents connecting to specific instances of your roles. But great addition to this topic!

Comment: the link is broken. May be this can be helpful http://geekswithblogs.net/shaunxu/archive/2013/11/02/remote-debug-windows-azure-cloud-service.aspx

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by using the Visual Studio Remote Debugger. There are a few steps you have to take in order to enable this. In short:

1. Install the remote debugger agent on the azure role
2. Create a virtual network group joining your local machine with the azure role
3. use the remote debugger

A more detailed explanation can be found here:
http://www.4tecture.ch/blog/remote-debugging-a-windows-azure-role-instance

Comment: I can now connect to the remote (azure) machine running the web role. Couldn't see w3wp.exe process until I made the 1st HTTP request. Then, when I attach to the w3wp.exe process, I get "No source available: The current thread is not running code or the call stack could not be obtained" in VS2012. Same when I pause the process. I did upload/deploy the debug build ... any ideas?

Comment: @DeepSpace101 Thanks for the `w3wp.exe` shout-out, I was attaching to the wrong process (from VS2013)